# Custom route transaction error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I was trying to implement custom animations for a screen but I'm encountering an error.

The error is:

> The getter 'isInitialRoute' isn't defined for the type 'RouteSettings'.

This is my code...

```
class MyCustomRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
      MyCustomRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
          : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

      @override
      Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          Widget child) {
        if (settings.isInitialRoute)
          return child;
        // Fades between routes. (If you don't want any animation, 
        // just return child.)
        return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
      }
    }
```

A help will be appreciated!

Thank-you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After searching around, I found the solution for this.

So I thought I would answer my own question.

Flutter updated the function ans we just have to use ***settings.name*** instead of ***settings.isInitialRoute***

```
class MyCustomRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
      MyCustomRoute({ WidgetBuilder builder, RouteSettings settings })
          : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

      @override
      Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context,
          Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          Widget child) {
        if (settings.name == '/') {
             return child;
        // Fades between routes. (If you don't want any animation, 
        // just return child.)
        return new FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: child);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The isInitialRoute property in RouteSetting has been deprecated. [Read more here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/route-navigator-refactoring).

Instead you can do:

```
MaterialApp(
  initialRouteName: ‘yourRouteName’,
```

Or:

```
onGenerateInitialRoutes: (String initialRouteName) {
    return <Route>[YourRoute()];
  }
```

Please note that your `initialRoute` is the first route in `Navigator`. It refers as `/`. So, if you want you can do this also: `settings.name == '/'`.