# Whats the alternative to if (routeSettings.isInitialRoute) in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

since isInitialRoute was removed from flutter, what else could i use instead? (the initial route is /  , if we can address that directly)

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        child: Navigator(
          key: navigationKey,
          initialRoute: initialRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings routeSettings) {
            WidgetBuilder builder = routes[routeSettings.name];
            if (routeSettings.isInitialRoute) {
              return PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: (context, __, ___) => builder(context),
                settings: routeSettings,
              );
            } else {
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: builder,
                settings: routeSettings,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        onWillPop: () {
          if(navigationKey.currentState.canPop()) {
            navigationKey.currentState.pop();
            return Future<bool>.value(false);
          }
          return Future<bool>.value(true);
        },
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `settings.name=='/'` as `routeSettings.isInitialRoute` is deprecated. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458936/custom-route-transaction-error-in-flutter)